# Is it possible to have different roles assigned to different web services in the same application?

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

**ENVIRONMENT**: JEE6, GlassFish 3.1, NetBeans 7

I have two roles, `ADMIN` and `USER`. I secured my Metro web service with HTTP Basic Authentication. However there are some webmethods that I want to be unaccessible for regular `USER`'s. I was thinking of separating the two 'types' of webmethods in two separate web services, plus somehow making them have a different path. This way I could set up two different `<security-constraint>`-s with different URL patterns, like this:

```xml
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secure Area A</web-resource-name>
    <description/>
    <url-pattern>/SecureWS_A/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
...
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secure Area B</web-resource-name>
    <description/>
    <url-pattern>/SecureWS_B/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
```

But I couldn't find a way to do so other than having two separate web applications which I don't really want to do. Is it possible to do this another way?

Comment: A programmatic solution would be to implement a Filter around your whole secure area that can do more fine grained URL/User matching.

Comment: Which part is not working? Separating the web services to two paths? Or setting the security-constraint tags?

Comment: @palacsint The only thing I don't know how to do: How to make two web services have different paths, so I can set up security for each of the two url patterns. Also I want to do this in one web application. Or from an other view: Is it possible to define URL patterns that differentiate web services in a single web application? Should I just use the full path of the web service instead of the `/*` regex kind of thing.

Comment: What are the (full) paths of your web services now?

Comment: @palacsint `https://localhost:8181/DataStore/AdminDataStore?wsdl` and `https://localhost:8181/DataStore/UserDataStore?wsdl`